# How to access key value pairs under array of objects of array of objects - java script

Tags: javascript

Here I want to access x1data and y1data..I tried to use some of the ways but that is not working as expected..i tried to access like values[0][0] but getting undefined. I don't know this is right way to get or not..can any one help me to get these inside object.

```js
var values = [
   {
      "xdata":[
         {
            "x1data":[
               {
                  "id":"name",
                  "email":"email"
               }
            ],
            "y1data":[
               {
                  "pno":"pno",
                  "pin":"pin"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: `values[0]['xdata'][0]['x1data']`

Comment: Find whoever designed this data format, and beat them until they change it to something sensible - either an Array or an Object, but not both!

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation and dot notation. Read more here [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). Below is a simple demo.

```js
var values = [{
  "xdata": [{
    "x1data": [{
      "id": "name",
      "email": "email"
    }],
    "y1data": [{
      "pno": "pno",
      "pin": "pin"
    }]
  }]
}]

console.log(values[0].xdata[0].x1data[0].id)
console.log(values[0].xdata[0].x1data[0].email)
// or

console.log(values[0]['xdata'][0]['x1data'][0]['id'])
console.log(values[0]['xdata'][0]['x1data'][0]['email'])
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Here data is dynamic, and we don't know the key names like xdata, x1data and y1data..

Comment: @Roy in that case use the Object.keys to get all the keys and then iterate over that array to access it further..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `values` structure doesn't change ( otherwise , you will need exception handling too )

```js
var values = [
    {
        "xdata": [
            {
                "x1data": [
                    {
                        "id": "name",
                        "email": "email"
                    }
                ],
                "y1data": [
                    {
                        "pno": "pno",
                        "pin": "pin"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]



for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    let firstObjKeys = Object.keys(values[i]);
    firstObjKeys.map(keyName => {
        for (j = 0; j < values[i][keyName].length; j++) {
            let secondObjKeys = Object.keys(values[i][keyName][j]);
            secondObjKeys.map(keyName2 => {
                for (z = 0; z < values[i][keyName][j][keyName2].length; z++) {
                    let thirdObjKeys = Object.keys(values[i][keyName][j][keyName2][z]);
                    thirdObjKeys.map(keyName3 => {
                        console.log(keyName3, values[i][keyName][j][keyName2][z][keyName3]);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```